# Line + multiple probability ribbon plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I saw this example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tibble(x = 1:10) %>%
  group_by_all() %>%
  do(tibble(y = rnorm(100, .$x))) %>%
  median_qi(.width = c(.5, .8, .95)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  # automatically uses aes(ymin = .lower, ymax = .upper, fill = fct_rev(ordered(.width)))
  geom_lineribbon() +
  scale_fill_brewer()
```

[image]

I am unable to get this to work. However my primary wish is to create this style of plot with these data for example:

```
data=data.frame("X"=c(,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
"Y"=c(,0.543160081,0.123664226,0.279783318,0.018285181,0.195599163,0.898118186,0.269707207,0.147648303,0.58262213,0.226656577),
"y"=c(,0.476366198,0.06718906,0.247566376,-0.080645752,0.163463818,0.819419124,0.228511531,0.104004353,0.568254655,0.175087503),
"yUL1"=c(,0.486366198,0.07718906,0.257566376,-0.070645752,0.173463818,0.829419124,0.238511531,0.114004353,0.578254655,0.185087503),
"yLL1"=c(,0.466366198,0.05718906,0.237566376,-0.090645752,0.153463818,0.809419124,0.218511531,0.094004353,0.558254655,0.165087503),
"yUL2"=c(,0.526366198,0.11718906,0.297566376,-0.030645752,0.213463818,0.869419124,0.278511531,0.154004353,0.618254655,0.225087503),
"yLL2"=c(,0.426366198,0.01718906,0.197566376,-0.130645752,0.113463818,0.769419124,0.178511531,0.054004353,0.518254655,0.125087503),
"yUL3" = c(0.556366198,0.14718906,0.327566376,-0.000645752,0.243463818,0.899419124,0.308511531,0.184004353,0.648254655,0.255087503),
"yLL3" =(0.396366198,-0.01281094,0.167566376,-0.160645752,0.083463818,0.739419124,0.148511531,0.024004353,0.488254655,0.095087503))
```

X is the black line and the bands go with the colors shown

Comment: It's unclear to me what the question is exactly. You tried that code example with the posted data and it didn't work? How?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to install and load the `tidybayes` package, which includes the `median_qi`, so that's why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your dataframe into a longer format by using `melt` function from `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
ylow <- c("yLL1","yLL2","yLL3")
yup <- c("yUL1","yUL2","yUL3")
dt <- melt(setDT(data), measure = list(ylow,yup), value.name = c("Low","End"))
```

Then, you can plot it using `geom_ribbon`

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt, aes(x = X, y = y))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Low, ymax = End, fill = as.factor(variable)), alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_line(color = "black")+
  scale_fill_brewer()
```

[image]

**EDIT: Using `tidybayes`**

If you want to use `tidybayes` package (that you forgot to mention in your question) and the function `geom_lineribbon`, you can change the name of variables when reshaping your dataframe into a longer format in order to match default names used by `geom_lineribbon`:

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidybayes)

ylow <- c("yLL1","yLL2","yLL3")
yup <- c("yUL1","yUL2","yUL3")
dt <- melt(setDT(data), measure = list(ylow,yup), value.name = c(".lower",".upper"), variable.name = ".width")

ggplot(dt, aes(x = X, y = y))+
  geom_lineribbon()+
  scale_fill_brewer()
```

And you get:
[image]

For some reasons, it looks a little bit different compared to `geom_ribbon`.

Does it look what you are trying to achieve ?

---

NB: Please check your reproducible dataset, there is some mistakes with extra comma and missing "c". Also, in your example, it's not clear waht represent both Y values.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to plot 3 separate instances of `geom_ribbon`, like this:

```r
data %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = X, y = y)) + 
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = yLL3, ymax=yUL3), fill = "#DEEBF7") +
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = yLL2, ymax=yUL2), fill = "#9ECAE1") + 
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = yLL1, ymax=yUL1), fill = "#3182BD") + 
 theme_bw()
```

[image]

I haven't added a `geom_line` because of how thin your middle band is, but this would be as simple as `+ geom_line()`